# Why doesn't this JQuery-Custom-Content-Scroller work for me when I have followed all instructions in their tutorial?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

[**Find the JSFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/yjazLf3e/4/)

I am trying to use the [malihu JQuery Custom Scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) plugin, and **I have followed the requirements and steps (atleast I think so) as follows**, but it does not seem to work for me. How do I get this to work?

1. > Extract and upload jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js, jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css and mCSB_buttons.png to your web server

I did that, and just cross checked.

2. > Include jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css in the head tag your HTML document...Include jQuery library... and jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js in the head tag...

I did that.

3. > **The element(s) you want to add scrollbar(s) should have the typical
   >   CSS properties of an overflowed block which are a height (or
   >   max-height) value, an overflow value of auto (or hidden) and content
   >   long enough to require scrolling.**

**The element to which I am applying the scrollbars is `.content-text` which occurs twice. It has `height: 100%; overflow: auto;`, and a bunch of text where the normal scroll bar does appear.**

4. > After files inclusion, call mCustomScrollbar function on the element
   >   selector you want to add the scrollbar(s).

I did that first by adding the [script](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/#expand-info) and changing the selector in the `script.js` **which gave me a bunch of JSLint errors**. So I tried to add the script to the end of the document before the body tag as you can see in the code. But No gain!

5. > Add the class mCustomScrollbar to any element you want to add custom
   >   scrollbar(s) with default options.

I added the `mCustomScrollbar` to the `.content-text` element, as you can see in the code.

---

***CODE:***

```js
(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){

        $("content-text").mCustomScrollbar({
            theme:"minimal"
        });

    });
})(jQuery);

/*
Produces the following JSLint errors:

11 Expected exactly one space between 'function' and '('. (function($){
11 Expected exactly one space between ')' and '{'. (function($){
11 Missing space between ')' and '{'. (function($){
12 Missing 'use strict' statement. $(window).load(function(){
12 Expected exactly one space between 'function' and '('. $(window).load(function(){
12 Expected exactly one space between ')' and '{'. $(window).load(function(){
12 Missing space between ')' and '{'. $(window).load(function(){
15 Missing space between ':' and 'minimal'. theme:"minimal"
19 Move the invocation into the parens that contain the function. })(jQuery);
19 'jQuery' was used before it was defined. })(jQuery);
*/
```

```css
.wrapper {
    height:100%;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: table;
    background-color:teal;
}

.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.left-cell {
    width:50%
}

.middle-cell {
    height:100%;
    background-color: white;
    width:1.5px;
    font-size: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 50px 10px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 50px 10px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 50px 10px black;
}

.right-cell {
   /* width:50%*/ /*Commenting b/c both right and left 50, 50 squish and vanish the middle between them*/
    background-color: blueviolet
}



.step-container {
    max-height: 200px;
    font-size: 0;
}

.right-cell .step-container {
    margin-top:100px;
}



.content-box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 170px;
    height: 200px;
    /*border: 5px solid blue;*/
    font-size: 0;
}

.content-box .content-image {
    width:35%;
    height:100%;
    background-size: cover;
    display: inline-block
}

.content-box .content-text {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);  
    color: #1c1a1a;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 100;
    overflow:auto;
    display: inline-block;
    width:65%;
    height:100%;
}

.notch-outer-container {
    display:inline-block;
}

.left-cell .notch-outer-container {
    margin-right: 3px;
}

.right-cell .notch-outer-container {
    margin-left: 3px;
}

.notch-inner-container {
    height:200px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.notch {
    width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-top: 15px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
}

.right-face-notch {
 border-left: 15px solid brown;
}

.left-face-notch {
    border-right: 15px solid brown;
}

.number-outer-container {
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
}

.left-cell .number-outer-container {
    left:47.5%;
}

.right-cell .number-outer-container {
    right:48%;
}

.number-inner-container {
    height:200px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.number-banner {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:crimson;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px; 
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.right-cell .number-outer-container {
    /*display: none;*/
}
```

```html
<link href="http://malihu.github.io/custom-scrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://malihu.github.io/custom-scrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- NOTE: THE INSTRUCTIONS AT http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/#expand-info DO INSTRUCT TO ALSO LOAD THE IMAGE AT "//malihu.github.io/custom-scrollbar/mCSB_buttons.png" BUT THIS SO TOOL DOES NOT LET ME LINK TO AN EXTERNAL IMAGE. 

i HAVE ADDED THAT IN THE JSFiddle I HAVE LINKED IN THE QUESTION. SO CHECK THAT-->


<!DOCTYPE>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" />
    <script src="javascript/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
</head>
    
<body>
    <div class="wrapper" >
        
        
        
        <div class="left-cell cell" align="left">
            <div class="step-container">
                <div class="content-box">
                        <div class="content-image" style="background-image: url(http://simeonhookphotography.com/wp-content/gallery/favorites/norway-countryside-to-bergen.jpg);"></div>
                        <div class="content-text mCustomScrollbar"
                             ><h6>What is Lorem Ipsum</h6><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p></div>
                    </div>

                
                <div class="notch-outer-container">
                    <div class="notch-inner-container">
                        <div class="right-face-notch notch"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                

                <div class="number-outer-container">
                    <div class="number-inner-container">
                        <div class="number-banner"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        
        
        <div class="middle-cell cell"></div>
        
        
        
        
        <div class="right-cell cell" align="right" >
            <div class="step-container">
                <div class="number-outer-container">
                    <div class="number-inner-container">
                        <div class="number-banner"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="notch-outer-container">
                    <div class="notch-inner-container">
                        <div class="left-face-notch notch"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="content-box">
                    <div class="content-text mCustomScrollbar"><h6>What is Lorem Ipsum</h6><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p></div>
                    <div class="content-image" style="background-image:url(http://www.penttila-gardens.com/activities/walking/countryside/images/02-harvest.jpg)">
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
         </div>
    
    
    </div>
    
    <script>
  (function($){
   $(window).load(function(){
    
    $("content-text").mCustomScrollbar({
     theme:"minimal"
    });
    
   });
  })(jQuery);
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

***EDIT:***

i added the following in the end of the document just before closing the `<body>` tag:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="javascript/jquery-2.1.3.js"><\/script>')</script>

    <!-- custom scrollbar plugin -->
    <script src="../jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        (function($){
            $(window).load(function(){

                $("content-text").mCustomScrollbar({
                    theme:"minimal"
                });

            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

But still getting the following errors in Chrome:

[image]

And the scroll-bars don't appear in firefox.

Comment: why did you load Jquery edge -- looks ok when you use Jquery v1.11 -- http://jsfiddle.net/tfaf78xd/

Comment: @Tasos I have JQuery 2.1.3 on my local server, and wasn't working there. When I created this JSFiddle, I clicked Edge because I thought that was the latest. Anyways, that seems to work, so if you can post that as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @Tasos Hey, NO, the scrollbars are not scrolling there. Do you have any idea why??

Comment: what browser are you using. chrome, IE scrollbars are ok

Comment: @Tasos Firefox. I needed it to work on at least Firefox, and Chrome =(

Comment: @Tasos Did you copy the exact code from the question, because it is not working in Chrome either. I am getting some weird errors in Chrome. I am posting a screen shot of them in the question.

Comment: @Solace you get the last error because of the 1st and the 3rd error, you should not ignore them. Somehow the page doesn't seem to load the scrollbar js code

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're loading jquery. There are a lot of examples in the github repository, you can start from there.

Have a look at this: https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/blob/master/examples/callbacks_example.html#L89

```
    <!-- Google CDN jQuery with fallback to local -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../js/minified/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Comment: Please see the edit in the question. I did add these, but it's not working yet.

Answer (score 0):

Set a particular value for the height i.e change the 100% to something like 600px;

```
 .content-box .content-text {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);  
        color: #1c1a1a;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 100;
        overflow:auto;
        display: inline-block;
        width:65%;
        height:100%; //assign a particular value to the height, say 600px;
}
```